# How do I install GRUB on bad EFI system?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, bootloader

I have an EFI system. I am able to boot from live USB in EFI mode.

However, when I try to install GRUB, system reboots and I see "GRUB" which also appears every time I press any key.

I was able to install EFI BOOTMGR when installing Windows 7. I still had to fix bootloader. When uninstalling it, I had to remove two "Windows Boot Manager" variables and one "BootOrder" (IIRC) on GNU/Linux. Every time my system rebooted, *but variables were removed.*

Is it possible to manually install GRUB on this system? How?

Comment: Will this be a Linux-only system or are you planning to dual-boot GRUB and Windows?

Comment: @grawity, currently, GNU/Linux‐only.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's a GRUB-only system – just provide what the firmware wants to see.

- The Windows boot manager is located at:

  ```
  \EFI\Microsoft\Bootmgfw.efi
  ```
- If boot entries are completely missing, all firmwares use a default fallback path:

  ```
  \EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi
  ```

Copy your `grubx64.efi` file to one of these locations (or both) and it should start just fine. This does prevent you from having the *real* Windows boot manager, however.

Comment: It looks like GRUB creates some boot entry, because my system reboots when doing grub-install. You should explain what is done by grub-install, so I can do this manually.

Comment: It works, but it looks like *hack*. I have executed command `efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sda --part 1 --write-signature --loader /EFI/GRUB/grubx64.efi --label "GRUB" --verbose`,  but it doesn't work ("GRUB" any key message).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have corrupted UEFI, so consider re‐flashing it. Sometimes, modified UEFI will help.

If no variables are present, issuing `efibootmgr` after installing GRUB has the following output:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 10 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* your_name
```